# reject doesn't break the promise operation

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

i have 2 insert query that i need to chain to each other by transaction cuz sometime one of those query may fail (thats by design), i use promise to handle what happens next

```
new Promise(function(resolve , reject ) {
        pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            connection.beginTransaction(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err.sqlMessage);
                }
                connection.query('INSERT INTO main_table  SET ?', main_table_data, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        connection.rollback(function () {
                            reject(err.sqlMessage)
                        });
                    }

                    connection.query('INSERT INTO child_table  SET ?', child_table_data, function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            connection.rollback(function () {
                                reject(err.sqlMessage)
                            });
                        }
                        connection.commit(function (err) {
                            if (err) {
                                connection.rollback(function () {
                                    reject(err.sqlMessage)
                                });
                            }
                            resolve(result.insertId);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    })

.then(function (ID) {

        console.log('/////////SUCCESS/////////////');
        console.log(ID);

})
.catch(function (error) {

    console.log('/////////ERROR/////////////');
    console.log(error);

});
```

the problem is i cant stop it from breaking the whole code , it execute the catch part

```
.catch(function (error) {

    console.log('/////////ERROR/////////////');
    console.log(error);

});
```

but the code inside the promise will go on instead of breaking ... this part specifically

```
  resolve(result.insertId);
```

this is my output

```
/////////ERROR/////////////
invalid wallet
C:\wamp64\www\expbet\serv\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
```

which is the output im expecting in the `catch` , but right after im getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertId' of undefined
```

cuzed by this code

```
  resolve(result.insertId);
```

why its still running resolve code if its been already rejected ? what im doing wrong

that second error breaks the whole node code , if thats not how reject works and i need to throw an error how can i do it without breaking the whole code and catch it in the promise catch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why its still running resolve code if its been already rejected?

Take a look at your `if(err) { reject(err.sqlMessage); }` clauses. None of them has an `else {}` clause therefore execution will continue as if there had been no error.

> What im doing wrong?

You are assuming that the occurrence of an error and/or calling `connection.rollback()` and/or calling `reject()` in the nodebacks will inhibit further execution of code. This is not the case.

Comment: thanx , i thought by rejecting the promise will stop the execution of the code ... kinda like throwing an error

Comment: I can understand the confusion. In a promise chain, the behaviour is as you describe. Hovever, in a `new Promise(...)` constructor, you're not yet in a promise chain. It's just standard, synchronously executed, line-by-line code.

Comment: you mean if the reject was in `.then` scope it would have worked as i thought?

Comment: Kind of. In `.then()` and `.catch()` callbacks, `reject()` is no longer appropriate. You have to `throw new Error(...)` instead. In a nutshell, `throw` is analogous to `reject()` and `return` is analagous to `resolve()`.

Comment: In other words, in a `new Promise(...)` constructor, you call `resolve()` and `reject()`. In `then(...)`/`catch(...)` callbacks, you use keywords `return` and `throw` respectively.

Comment: One small but important detail is that by returing a Promise (from a `then()`/`catch()` callback), the eventual outcome of that stage in your Promise chain is determined by the fate of that returned Promise. At the time the Promise is returned, even though its fate is not known, all you need to do is `return` it. A Promise need never, and should never, be thrown.